# Tackling Scalability and Performance Issues in a Distributed A* Search Algorithm for Large Graphs

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, graph, path-finding

I've been working on a project that involves searching through graphs with millions of nodes and edges. The size is expected to grow exponentially in the future. To do this, I decided to implement a version of the A* search algorithm that is both highly scalable and fault-tolerant.

Here's an overview of what I have done so far:

1. Made multi-threading system to explore multiple nodes at once.
2. Implementd priority queue to manage the open set in a more better manner.
3. Made a distributed key-value store for storing the graph data.
4. Designed a checkpointing system to save the progress at regular intervals, enabling recovery from unexpected failures.

Despite these efforts, the algorithm's performance still isn't meeting my expectations, and the fault tolerance mechanisms are adding a considerable amount of overhead.

How can I further enhance the scalability and performance of my distributed A* search algorithm while retaining fault tolerance capabilities?

Comment: There are research paper on the topic. Many variants of A* has been developed to improve A* performance. AFAIK, HPA* should be a good start. IDK for the fault tolerance part. Note that A* tends not to scale well on many machines but this is quite expected regarding the problem itself. I do not think using key-value storage will be efficient for this, locality is important for performance, especially here. Millions of nodes does not seems so big so to use distributed computation. It looks like using a hammer to me (so not very efficient). IDK though for the fault tolerance part though.

Comment: AFAIK, for the fault tolerance part, the key point is the MTBF. With a high MTBF, it might be better to use replication. Otherwise, checkpointing is fine. Most platforms are quite reliable so rare checkpointing are enough (especially with a suitable hardware like ECC, good components, a low frequency, etc.) unless you use a supercomputer (which looks oversized for a million node/edge graph).